# How to show WP Comment in android retrofit

Tags: android, json

I want load data from server and for it i use `Retrofit`. I want load post (**title**, **description**, **image** and more...) and with data i want load comments from this post. 
I can load **title**, **description**, **image** and more... and show its. but i don't know how can i show post comments in activity!

**ModelResponse (with getter and setter) :**

```
public class R_CatModelResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    public String Cat_status;
    @SerializedName("count")
    public int Cat_count;
    @SerializedName("pages")
    public int Cat_pages;
    @SerializedName("category")
    public Retrofit_ColoniesModel category;
    @SerializedName("posts")
    public List<R_CatModel> Cat_posts;
```

**Model (with getter and setter) :**

```
public class R_CatModel {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public Integer id;
    @SerializedName("type")
    public String type;
    @SerializedName("slug")
    public String slug;
    @SerializedName("url")
    public String url;
    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;
    @SerializedName("title_plain")
    public String title_plain;
    @SerializedName("content")
    public String content;
    @SerializedName("excerpt")
    public String excerpt;
    @SerializedName("date")
    public String date;
    @SerializedName("modified")
    public String modified;
    @SerializedName("comment_count")
    public int comment_count;
    @SerializedName("comment_status")
    public String comment_status;
    @SerializedName("thumbnail")
    public String thumbnail;
    @SerializedName("thumbnail_images")
    public R_CatThumbnailImages thumbnail_images;
    @SerializedName("categories")
    public List<R_CatCategory> categories;
    @SerializedName("author")
    public R_CatAuthor catAuthor;
    @SerializedName("comments")
    public List<R_PostComment> comments;
```

**PostComment (with getter and setter):**

```
@SerializedName("id")
public int cmID;
@SerializedName("name")
public String cmName;
@SerializedName("url")
public String cmUrl;
@SerializedName("date")
public String cmDate;
@SerializedName("content")
public String cmContent;
@SerializedName("parent")
public int cmParent;
```

**Adapter codes (for load comments) :**

```
public class CommentAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentAdapter2.ViewHolder> {

    private List<R_PostComment> mDataSet;
    private Context context;

    public CommentAdapter2(Context context, List<R_PostComment> mDataSet) {
        this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CommentAdapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CommentAdapter2.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        viewHolder.comment_name.setText( ??? );
        viewHolder.comment_date.setText( ??? );
        viewHolder.comment_content.setText(Html.fromHtml( ??? ));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView comment_name, comment_content, comment_date;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            comment_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_userName_text);
            comment_content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_comment_text);
            comment_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_date_text);
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity codes:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.post_show_page);

        bindActivity();

        // Initialize
        favDB = new FavHelper(context);

        //Give Data
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            postID = bundle.getInt("postID");
            title = bundle.getString("title");
            image = bundle.getString("image");
            content = bundle.getString("content");
            dateTime = bundle.getString("dateTime");
            author = bundle.getString("author");
            category = bundle.getString("category");
            categoryID = bundle.getString("categoryID");
        }

        mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
        // Setup comment RecyclerView
        comment_Recyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        comment_Recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);

        startAlphaAnimation(mTitle, 0, View.INVISIBLE);

        // Set Data into views
        if (title != null) {
            postShow_title.setText(title);
            postShow_title2.setText(title);
            title_sliding.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.comment_title) + " " + title);
        }
        loadPostProgressDialog.createAndShow(this);
        if (image != null) {
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(image)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.post_image)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target,
                                                       boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            loadPostProgressDialog.dissmis();
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(post_cover);
        }

        if (content != null) {
            post_content_web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            WebSettings settings = post_content_web.getSettings();
            settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

            post_content_web.loadData(content, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
        }
        if (dateTime != null) {
            postShow_dateTime.setText(dateTime);
        }
        if (author != null) {
            postShow_author.setText(author);
        }
        if (category != null) {
            postShow_category.setText(category);
        }

        post_cover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                BlurBehind.getInstance().execute(PostShow_page.this, new OnBlurCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBlurComplete() {
                        startActivity(new Intent(PostShow_page.this, DialogImage_page.class)
                                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)
                                .putExtra("imageCover", image));

                    }
                });
            }
        });
        postShow_category.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (categoryID != null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(PostShow_page.this, Category_page.class)
                            .putExtra("categoryID", categoryID)
                            .putExtra("categoryTitle", category));
                }
            }
        });

    private void bindData() {

        // Setup Connect
        Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);

        call.enqueue( ??? )

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(PostShow_page.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

**ApiInterface :**

```
@GET("?json=get_category_posts")
Call<R_CatModelResponse> getCatResponse(@Query("id") Integer id);
```

**JSON link :** [Link][1] , with `id= ?` (end of `json` link) i send **categoryID** for see this category posts!

How can i show comments from posts in this posts ?
 Thanks all <3

Answer (score 0):

In your activity's class. When you do:

```
call.enqueue()
```

Let's assume you're getting the body back correctly, because you said that you can load the title, description, and image.

So you probably have something like:

```
R_CatModelResponse catModelResponse;
call.enqueue(new CallBack<R_CatModelResponse>()
{
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Response<R_CatModelResponse> response)
        {
            catModelResponse = response.body();
        }
}
```

....

```
List<R_CatModel> catPosts = catModelResponse.getCat_posts();
//For whatever index of the posts you're interested in. Take 0 for example:
List<R_PostComment> comments = catPosts.get(0).getCatPosts();
```

You can use the getter for "R_CatModel" to get the List then use the getter for R_CatModel to retrieve the List of R_PostComment. When you get that List comments object, pass that into your RecycerView's adapter (CommentAdapter2). So something like the following inside your activity:

```
CommentAdapter2 adapter = new CommentAdapter2(this, comments);
comment_Recyclerview.set(adapter);
```

Note that since Retrofit's enqueue call is asynchronous, you should do your RecyclerView's setup after the call is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
private void bindData() {
    // Setup Connect
    Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
    Call<R_PostModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getPostResponse(postID);
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.show();
    Log.d("PostID", "Post : " + postID);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<R_PostModelResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<R_PostModelResponse> call, Response<R_PostModelResponse> response) {

            if (response.body() != null) {

                models.addAll(response.body().getPost().getComments());
                Log.e("testComment", "" + response.body().getPost().getComment_count());
                mAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();

                comment_Recyclerview.setAdapter(mAdaper);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

            } else {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<R_PostModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(PostShow_page.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```